# Python subprocess.Popen() does not transfer ® symbol and instead translates the literal letter 'r' as argument to batch file

Tags: python, shell, encoding, subprocess

I am writing a Python script to run a batch file and give it several arguments to input throughout the batch script. Unfortunately, when I run across the special character ® , the batch script recognizes it as a literal letter 'r'. My code currently looks like this (along with a bunch of code I've tried and later commented out. I also left my comments in so you can get an idea of what I have tried and where my mindset is):

```
    item = subprocess.Popen('"file.bat", {}, {}, {}, {}'.format(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4), universal_newlines=True, encoding='utf-8', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) #stdin=subprocess.PIPE #shell=True # Manually added ^® to input which also failed. CMD recognizes ® but displays 'r' when typing. 
    # item = item.communicate(str.encode("utf-8"))
    # data = item.communicate()
    # print(data[0])
    for line in item.stdout:
        print(line) # .decode('utf-8')

    # Since windows displays 'r' but still recognizes the character as ®, the process is interpreting the literal text on the prompt. Need to interpret the value. Tried encoding parameters to no avail. 
    # Try stdin=subprocess.PIPE with encode('utf-8)
    # Try removing r in beginning of .Popen
```

I have the arguments in double quotes.

I've tried several variations of encoding 'utf-8'

I tried making Popen read as a string literal using r'"file.bat", {}, {}, {}, {}'

I've noticed that when I paste ® to the Visual Studio Code terminal, it will initially display as 'r', however if I echo it the resulting display will be ®.

I tried using an escape character ^®

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue in a roundabout way. It looks like by passing in arguments to a python.exe it may be avoided altogether.

I copy pasted the [extended version](https://www.ascii-code.com/) of the ASCII table (characters not supported by batch files) into a text file, then saved it to excel as a tab separated file with 'utf-8' encoding. From there I read through it as a dataframe using Pandas.

```
    df = pd.read_csv('extended_ascii.csv')
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        char = row['Symbol']
        BIN = row['BIN']
        arg1 = arg1.replace(char, "BIN" + str(BIN))
        arg2 = arg2.replace(char, "BIN" + str(BIN))
        arg3 = arg3.replace(char, "BIN" + str(BIN))
        arg4 = arg4.replace(char, "BIN" + str(BIN))
```

-Run Batch File-

Back in python script:

```
    for line in Lines:
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            char = row['Symbol']
            BIN = row['BIN']
            line = line.replace("BIN" + str(BIN), char)
```

It is unlikely any of my argument text will contain BIN######## which seems to be the only weakness using this method.